# Finding k elements in array whose product equals given number

Tags: algorithm

Given an array `a` of `n` nonnegative integers and two integers `k` and `m`, find `k` elements of `a` whose product equals `m` (return their indices). Input is guaranteed to have a solution.

So bruteforce algorithm would check all possible combinations, which is O(n!/(k!(n-k)!)) performance, but time constraints suggests that there is O(n log n) solution, that I'm struggling to find.

Comment: I would advice you to add some code or solution you have tried into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer for your homework and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: I guess that 15 lines of Python code which is unlikely to terminate before Sun's death on sufficiently big input is unnecessary

Comment: How about checking which of the elements of the array are divisors of `m` - that could  speed things up

Comment: This is a classic dynamic programming problem :] You cache intermediate results and multiplication ignores order (commutative).

Comment: @DavidSoroko it's still not clear what to do next, other than to try all possible combinations of `b` known divisors

Comment: @andrhua hint: let's say your array is `[a,b,c,d,e]` - if you already calculated `a*b*c` and are now calculating `a*b*d` you can reuse the value of `a*b`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum is correct, but we can also use the properties of integer multiplication to throw away all intermediate results that cannot possibly be on their way to a solution.  This greatly speeds the algorithm up.

Comment: This is NP-hard by reduction from Exact Cover.  Suppose we have an instance of EC with p sets and q elements in the universe.  Map the i-th element to the (p+i)-th prime number, and map each set to the product of its contained elements.  Finally, set m to the product of the (p+1)-th through (p+q)-th primes.  You have now constructed an instance of your problem which has a solution if and only if the original EC instance has a solution.

Comment: Hint for an algorithm: Suppose you have a bit array, in which the i-th element is 1 if and only if it's possible to produce the number i by multiplying some subset of the numbers from `a` that we have seen so far.  After processing all numbers in `a`, is there a quick way to tell *if* there is a solution?  How could you update this bit array to process the next number from `a`?  How big does the bit array need to be?

Comment: What are the constraints on the range of each element, m, n, and k?

Comment: I don't think dynamical programming would be eficient in this quest. It might turn out to be very memory hungry. I would first start with finding the prime factors of `m` and then set off with figuring out something nice.

Comment: גלעד ברקן: Element i is contained in set j iff a[j] divides the (p+i)-th prime number.  So e.g. if the EC instance is {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4}}, then p=3, q=4, and since the first few primes are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, we would create a[1] = 7*13, a[2] = 11*13, a[3] = 17 and set m = 7*11*13*17.  (Actually I was over-cautious...  We don't need to skip the first p primes -- it would be fine to map the i-th element straight to the i-th prime instead.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this can be solved by dynamic programming.

There are two ways to do dynamic programming.  Top down, and bottom up.  The tradeoff is that top down is easier to do.  But bottom up often can perform better.  Since you're struggling for a solution, I'll explain top down.

To do top down, you need to write a recursive algorithm, then [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  Memoizing means that if you have to calculate a result, you save it in cache.  The next time you don't do the calculation, you just return the cached value.  So you take a function that is something like this:

```
def foo(bar, baz):
    # do recursive stuff
    return answer
```

and then turn it into this:

```
cached_foo = {}
def foo (bar, baz):
    if (bar, baz) not in cached_foo:
        # Do recursive stuff
        cached_foo[(bar, baz)] = answer
    return cached_foo[(bar, baz)]
```

There may be complications in practice, but that is always the general idea.

In this case, the heart of your recursive algorithm will be this:

```
def reachable_factors(a, m, i, j):
    # Returns all factors of m that can be reached, and how to reach
    # them with j of the first i terms of a
    pass
```

This algorithm should be slow.  But once you memoize it, it will be fast.

---

Since another solution has been posted, here is a Python one.

```
def exact_factorization(a, m, k):
    cache = {}
    def reachable_factors(i, j):
        # This will be all of the ways to get to a factor of m
        # using j of the first i elements of a
        if (i, j) not in cache:
            # This is the recursive calculation
            answer = {}
            if i < j:
                # We cannot use more than i of the first i elements.
                pass
            elif 0 == j:
                # The empty product is 1
                answer = {1: None}
            else:
                # First, find all of the ways of not using this element.
                for (fact, path) in reachable_factors(i-1, j).iteritems():
                    answer[fact] = path

                # Note the potential off by one error.  The i'th
                # element is at i-1
                i_th = a[i-1]

                # Next,find all of the ways of using this element
                for (fact, path) in reachable_factors(i-1, j-1).iteritems():
                    if 0 == m % (fact * i_th):
                        answer[fact * i_th] = [i-1, path]

            cache[(i, j)] = answer
        return cache[(i, j)]

    reachable = reachable_factors(len(a), k)

    # The answer is now in reachable[m], but as a nested list in reverse
    # order.  We want to extract it in a better format.
    path = reachable[m]
    final_answer = []
    while path is not None:
        final_answer.append(path[0])
        path = path[1]
    return [x for x in reversed(final_answer)]

print(exact_factorization(
    [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 12], 12, 4
))
```

---

And here is the bottom up approach.  Note that its performance is the same as top down, but it requires less memory.  It also avoids Python's silly recursion limit.

```
def exact_factorization(a, m, k):
    partial_answers = [{1: None}]
    for _ in range(k):
        partial_answers.append({})

    for i in range(len(a)):
        x = a[i]
        for j in range(k, 0, -1):
            these_answers = partial_answers[j]
            for fact, path in partial_answers[j-1].iteritems():
                if 0 == m % (x * fact):
                    these_answers[x * fact] = [i, path]

    reachable = partial_answers[k]

    if m not in reachable:
        return None

    # The answer is now in reachable[m], but as a nested list in reverse
    # order.  We want to extract it in a better format.
    path = reachable[m]
    final_answer = []
    while path is not None:
        final_answer.append(path[0])
        path = path[1]
    return [x for x in reversed(final_answer)]
```

Comment: The only thing that I did differently in the full solution was to put `reachable_factors` inside of the `exact_factorization` function.  That lets `a` and `m` be available without passing them around, and also causes the cache to naturally get thrown away.

Comment: okay, maybe it's not too late to take major in communications

Comment: Thank you for a such detailed explanation, in my case einstellung was that I've never used dynamic where its elements are complex structures and not plain numbers

Comment: @גלעדברקן The error is because there is no solution.  You just need a small check.  The recursion error is fixable with `sys.setrecursionlimit`.  And the complexity is `n * no_of_factors(m)`.  Which is quite reasonable.

Comment: Oops, the complexity is `O(n * k * no_of_factors(m))`.

Comment: When I try to run the bottom-up version with an array of about 1,000,000 elements where the 12 factors for `m = 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12` are distributed among other numbers, and `k = 12`, the program just keeps running (I didn't wait more than about half a minute). Am I doing something wrong or is this expected? Is there more memoization needed there? I would think that to be a reasonable input to handle quickly for a sound solution.

Comment: @גלעדברקן It took around 4 minutes on my laptop.  Note that the number of factors is 540, `k` is 12 and `n` is 1,000,000.  That makes it `O(6,480,000,000)` operations, where the inner loop of the operation includes at least one multiplication and division.  With the CPU going at 2.4 ghz, that's a bit under 100 cpu cycles per loop.  This, in an interpreted language.

Comment: So I would indeed call that time reasonable for this implementation.

Comment: Cool. My JS script ran it in 250 milliseconds. Can you think of an example where trying to enumerate subsets based on grouped permitted divisors (already presented in the array and limited by their potential max quantity in `m`), as I proposed, could present a challenge for an `m` under `2^64` and `1 ≤ n ≤ k ≤ 10,000,000`?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I would suggest `2^7*3^4*5^2*7^2*11*13*17*19*23*29*31*37*41 = 18,401,055,938,125,660,800` with an array that contains all 184,320 factors 7 times each and `k = 24`.  That's pretty much a worst case scenario.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with a Python implementation of my version - quit without an answer after about two hours and a few billion iterations. The dynamic program is also pretty slow, though, for that size input. Got to about 18,000 and stopped it. Interesting problem.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I would expect the dynamic program to take 2-3 days on my laptop.  I'm not sure how long yours would take.

Answer (score 0):

Map the numbers in the input array to their frequency. For the divisors of `m`, begin a recursive attempt to build subsets of size `k`, provided the subset elements exist in the map. Order the recursion such that the elements in the subset are ordered. Keep trying to divide the accumulator product by the next higher divisor of `m` (or the same if frequency allows), cutting off the recursion when the next division would yield a smaller divisor than the current one.

Here's a JavasScript example that does not handle frequencies (as chqrlie pointed out, repeated factors present an issue but we can handle them by only trying different sized groups of each):

```js
function f(A, m, k){
  let map = {}
  for (let a of A)
    map[a] = map[a] ? map[a] + 1: 1
  
  let ds = Object.keys(map).map(x => Number(x)).sort((a, b) => a - b)
 
  function g(es, i, p){
    if (es.length == k - 1 && map[p])
      return [es.concat(p)]
    if (i == ds.length ||
        p / ds[i] < ds[i] ||
        es.length + ds.length - i < k)
      return []
    
    let result = g(es, i + 1, p)

    if (!(p % ds[i]))
      result = result.concat(
        g(es.slice().concat(ds[i]), i + 1, p / ds[i]))
        
     return result
  }

  return g([], 0, m)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([15, 2, 3, 5, 30, 1], 30, 3)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([15, 2, 3, 5, 30, 1], 30, 2)))

let a = [1, 2]
for (let i=0; i<500000; i++)
  a.push(30)
a.push(5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
for (let i=0; i<500000; i++)
  a.push(15)
a.push(3,4)

let m = 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(a, m, 12)))
```

Comment: With m=15943230000000000000, k=7 and `let a=[]; for (let i=0; i<=13; i++) for (let j=0; j<=13; j++) for (let k=0; k<=6; k++) a.push(Math.pow(2, i) * Math.pow(3, j) * Math.pow(5, k*2))` (n=1183), this code takes 9 minutes 29 seconds on my machine to (correctly) return no solution.

Comment: But I discovered that the largest exactly representable integer in Javascript is 2^53-1, so I also tried to fit in that size: Using m=8503056000000000, k=7 and `let a=[]; for (let i=0; i<=10; i++) for (let j=0; j<=10; j++) for (let k=0; k<=5; k++) a.push(Math.pow(2, i) * Math.pow(3, j) * Math.pow(5, k*2))` (n=726) takes 50 seconds on my machine to (correctly) return no solution.

Comment: @j_random_hacker cool, I'm working on btilly's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984726/finding-k-elements-in-array-whose-product-equals-given-number/55985465?noredirect=1#comment98668788_55985073) with a version in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithmic complexity for testing all combinations explodes completely, but a brute force implementation can prune the test cases very efficiently: I am using a recursive function that tests if the `i`-th number in the array is a divisor of `m` and recurses on the rest of the list from the next element to find `k-1` divisors of `m` and iterates from the next element otherwise.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int found(int n, const int set[], int flags[], int i, int k, int m) {
    if (k <= 0)
        return m == 1;
    if (i >= n)
        return 0;
    if (set[i] == 0) {  // must special case 0
        if (m == 0) {
            if (i + k <= n) {
                while (k-- > 0)
                    flags[i++] = 1;
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (m % set[i] == 0) {
        if (found(n, set, flags, i + 1, k - 1, m / set[i])) {
            flags[i] = 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return found(n, set, flags, i + 1, k, m);
}

// get a number from the command line or from stdin
int getnum(int *index, char *argv[]) {
    int value;
    if (argv[*index]) {
        value = strtol(argv[(*index)++], NULL, 0);
        printf("%d ", value);
        return value;
    }
    if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, m, k, arg_i = 1;

    printf("enter n, k and m: ");
    n = getnum(&arg_i, argv);
    k = getnum(&arg_i, argv);
    m = getnum(&arg_i, argv);
    printf("\n");
    int set[n];
    int flags[n];
    printf("enter %d numbers: ", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        set[i] = getnum(&arg_i, argv);
        flags[i] = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
    if (found(n, set, flags, 0, k, m)) {
        for (int i = 0, j = k; i < n; i++) {
            if (flags[i])
                printf("%d %c ", set[i], --j > 0 ? '*' : '=');
        }
        printf("%d\n", m);
    } else {
        printf("no solution\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
chqrlie$ ./findfactors 20 5 720 {0..19}
enter n, k and m: 20 5 720 
enter 20 numbers: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
1 * 2 * 3 * 8 * 15 = 720
```

If a solution exists, I suspect it will be found in linear time in most cases. Te pathological case is if the array contains many divisors of `m`, especially the value `1`, and the solution involves a large factor at the end of the array or no solution at all. The complexity then does explode to **O(2<sup>N</sup>)**.

Examples of pathological cases:

```
chqrlie$ time ./findfactors 30 15 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
enter n, k and m: 30 15 2
enter 30 numbers: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
no solution

real    0m6.329s
user    0m6.213s
sys     0m0.039s

chqrlie$ time ./findfactors 34 12 65536 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 65536
enter n, k and m: 34 12 65536
enter 34 numbers: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 65536
1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 65536 = 65536

real    0m8.431s
user    0m8.283s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Comment: @גלעד ברקן: Both examples posted at the end of the answer exhibit **O(2^n)** complexity: they recurse more than 2^30 times for a set of 30 or so elements. Of course the algorithm can be tweaked to account for these pathological cases, by sorting the array in descending order and special casing the value `1`.

Comment: It's funny how the brain works. When I've seen your username, I always think charlie q, and just now noticed the q is actually in the middle :)

Comment: @גלעד ברקן: It is just a joke about the French keyboard where the letters `A` and `Q` are swapped.

Comment: We can special handle repeated factors to only try different sized groups of each. I don't see how O(2^n) would still be warranted then.